# I get the message org.openide.filesystems does not exist.

Tags: java, netbeans-7.3

Someone else asked this question, but I didn't see anything in the answer that would help me.  Why isn't my netbeans session finding this library?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I consulted with an expert at work and found the solution.  I had to add a library dependency for "File System API".  How that relates to an external library is one of the mysteries of netbeans.